# FPDF Header Image not showing on PDF

Tags: fpdf

I have a simple fpdf code but my header image not displaying... All other data are showing correct.

```
class PDF extends FPDF{

function Header(){
$this->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
$this->Ln(20);
}

function Footer()
{
$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}

}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",14);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have to add:

ob_end_clean();